# How to replace a page by date

Tags: c#, asp.net

There is way to replace page at some date&time ?

example: i want that at friday the default.aspx will down, and other page will turn to default.aspx... and then at sunday the first default.aspx will return.

someone have an idea? maybe will be better to change the display of the default.aspx. i need to replace the screen to "we down for a while" or something like that.

i mean that button will do that...

using c#. asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could create a second page that your users would go to when the page is down, and call it something like ApplicationDown.  Then, you could program a redirect to that page for Friday's and Saturday's only.

```
            if ((DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday && DateTime.Now.Hour >= 17) || 
                DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
            {
                Response.Redirect("ApplicationDown.aspx");
            }
```

Seems like an odd way of doing things, but that would work for you if you put it at the top of Default.aspx's page load.

Comment: well great, i can do that at the masterpage and then all the site will down right (all the pages that have that masterpage)? example: if someone remember that the site have link : www.mysite.com/bla.aspx and try to enter that link  ,and the bla.aspx have the masterpage - it will down, right?

Comment: Yeah, you can do it this way "(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday && DateTime.Now.Hour >= 17)"  Where the number is the hour you want to close on (in 24 hour format).  I updated the code in my answer to show this.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to turn your date-sensitive content into UserControl's and show different ones on the page based on the date.

Answer (score 0):

Just place file [app_offline.htm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f735abw9%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in your app root folder.

Comment: But wouldn't he have to do this manually every Friday?  Seems like he would like a more dynamic approach.  I've never heard of app_offline.aspx, so it's totally new to me as of right now, so please pardon any ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to display a down message, put this in your markup (not codebehind):

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <%if (DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
      { %>
        We're down.
    <%} else{ %>
        Insert regular site content here
    <%} %>
</asp:Content>
```

Mine is in a content, but looking at that should give you an idea of how it works.  Or you could also do this:

```
if (DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
    Response.Redirect("downmessage.aspx");
```

Comment: Of course, this assumes you already have a method to take your site down while still allowing users to get to default.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in default.aspx or its code behind:

`if(DateTime.Now > new DateTime(2011, 4, 23) && DateTime.Now < new DateTime(2011, 4, 30) )
      Response.Redirect("Down.aspx");`

So, if we are between 2011-04-23 and 2011-04-30, it will be redirected to "Down.aspx"